# Using SSL For Existing Web application-Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have used this article""[Microsoft Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287954%28office.12%29.aspx#Section2) to use SSL for my existing site and the web site comes up as IE cannot display the page.

Could anybody point me in the right direction please.

Thank you
Hari Gillala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article describes how to enable SSL for a web application, but you need to do a little more to get it to work.

http://faraz-khan.blogspot.com/2007/07/right-way-to-enable-ssl-on-moss-web.html

http://www.mukalian.com/blog/post/2008/12/26/How-To-SSL-Enable-a-Web-Application.aspx

Bascially

- Install the SSL certificate into IIS
- Create a site collection at the root
- Make sure your AAMs are correctly configured